# Is taking the mode of a duplicate classifier worth it?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a question about a classifier concept.

### case 1

If I have a classifier and the performance of that classifier up to 90%.
and I create n another classifier with the same algorithm and same dataset and get performance 90% too.

### case2

same like case 1 but every classifier with a different algorithm.

### Combinding the results

the result I get from

```
mode(classifier1,classifier2,classifier3,...,classifiern)
```

Is that technique worth it or useless (case1, and case2)?

Comment: Case 2 is called ensemble learning. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning

Comment: Might be more suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, case 1 and 2 are called ensemble learning. Both are worth it.

For case 1: please note that neural networks with the same architecture, same learning algorithm but different initial weights can have very different performance.

Similar to case 1 (taking the average, not the mode) are Schmidhubers averaging ensembles. I published some results of them with various datasets and network architectures in [my masters thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09725) (e.g. Table 5.2, Table 5.8, Table 5.9, Table 5.11, 5.13, ...).

### See also

- [Ensemble methods in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html)
- My Blog post: [Ensembles](https://martin-thoma.com/ensembles/)
- [Bagging, boosting and stacking in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187970/25741)